# Tree impurity of a call graph

Tags: terminology, graph, trees

In his "Software Engineering. Principles and Practice," H. van Vliet mentions "tree impurity of a call graph." However, the term *tree impurity* is not used in this meaning anywhere else but refers to decision trees in machine learning. Did H. v. V. misuse the term in his book, or has the term recently lost its original meaning?

Answer (score 3):

The full phrase is "It is therefore worthwhile to consider the tree impurity of a call graph, i.e. the extent to which the graph deviates from a pure tree". The defining property of a tree is that there are no cycles among its nodes, so the author considers a call graph "impure" if it contains cycles (i.e. direct or indirect recursion). This is explicitly confirmed later in that paragraph.

Comment: Thank you. I know what van Vliet's term means. My concern is that it is never used anywhere else in that meaning. Instead, it refers to the tree impurity of a decision tree and means a very different thing.